# Search Title In Access DataBase

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

**Background:**

I need to open an Access file and get the information there to make a comparison with the data in my Excel spreadsheet.

 I'm using Microsoft Office 15.0 Access db engine Object library instead of Microsoft DAO object library.

**Problem:**

 While I'm available to paste all the data with the following code, for some reason, it starts in "row 2" ignoring titles.

```
Sub Sample()
Const PathToDB = "C:\...\AccessFile.accdb"
Const TitleSampleTable = "Sample Table"
Dim BDSample As Database
Dim SampleTable As Recordset
Dim SampleTableDef As TableDef
Dim CounterTitles As Long
Dim CounterRows As Long
Dim ColToPasteIn As Long
Dim RowToPasteIn As Long
    Set BDSample = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(PathToDB)
    Set SampleTable = BDSample.OpenRecordset(TitleSampleTable, dbOpenDynaset)
    Set SampleTableDef = BDSample.TableDefs(TitleSampleTable)

    For CounterTitles = 0 To SampleTableDef.RecordCount
    RowToPasteIn = RowToPasteIn + 1
    ColToPasteIn = 1
    For CounterRows = 0 To SampleTable.Fields.Count
    With Sheets(TitleSampleTable)
    .Cells(RowToPasteIn, ColToPasteIn).Value = SampleTable.Fields(CounterRows) 'this is starts in the "body" of access, I can't figure a way to retrieve titles!
    ColToPasteIn = ColToPasteIn + 1
    End With
    Next CounterRows
    SampleTable.MoveNext
    Next CounterTitles
     Set BDSample = Nothing
     Set SampleTable = Nothing         
     Set SampleTableDef = Nothing
End Sub
```

Sample data in Accesss

[image]

Sample Data in Excel

[image]

**Questions:**

 How do I get the titles values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the field names and populate the row 1

```
For i = 0 To SampleTable.Fields.Count - 1
    Sheets(TitleSampleTable).Cells(1, i + 1) = SampleTable.Fields(i).Name
Next i
```

And then you can populate the date from row 2 onward as you were originally doing

Comment: Haha, simple enough! Thanks!